# В Ubuntu 12.04 не устанавливается драйвер Nvidia 173

Tags: nvidia, ubuntu

"Драйверы устройств" его вообще не показывает, а при установке из Центра приложений и Synaptic выдает

> зависимости пакетов не могут быть разрешены

Если скачать deb-пакет и попробовать установить его через Центр приложений, то пишет

> зависимость не может быть удовлетворена: xorg-video-abi-10

Как я понял, его предоставляет `xserver-xorg-core`, а он установлен.  В общем, что делать не знаю. `nvidia-current` ставится через "драйверы устройств", но глючит и всегда глючила, потому устанавливал 173. А в текущем релизе такая вот проблема.

Если кто как-то решил - жду советов.  Заранее спасибо!

P.S. Я не гик, так что если что-то примитивное написал, мне простительно.

Answer (score 1):

А что вам мешает установить драйвер взятый с официального сайта NVIDIA? На сколько мне известно, в DVD версии Ubuntu уже есть прикрученный проприетарный драйвер, посему установка свежего не вызывает проблем.

Comment: "Прикручен" драйвер версии 295.40, а он с проблемами. Unity 3-d и Gnome-shell с ним не запускаются (проблема явно в самом драйвере, потому что когда его удаляю и оставляют только свободные драйвер они (юнити 3-д и гном-шел) работают, правда притормаживают. Как я уже писал выше, драйвер "curren" работает с глюками начиная с ubuntu 11.04 (не помню точно, какая там версия драйвера была). У меня встроенная nvidia 6-ой серии.

Answer (score 0):

Надо найти пакет

> xorg-video-abi-10

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/xorg-video-abi-10Вот он. И xserver-xorg-core установлен. По идее зависимость должна быть удовлетворена. Либо я что-то не до конца понимаю

Comment: Пакет именно с таким названием, это доп. компонент к XServer

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, что nvidia 173 для компиляции нужна более старая версию xorg, чем есть в 12 убунте. Они уже в 11 по моему прикручивались только с бубном, через подключение репов для старых версий.

Comment: Может быть. Хотя в 11.4 и 11.10 у меня без бубна ставилось. В зависимостях 295.40 указан xorg-video-abi-11, а 173 - xorg-video-abi-10. Неужели в nVidia не могли совместимость наладить. Вышла новая версия драйвера 295.49. Пишут, что некоторые глюки убрали. Буду ждать,когда в репозитории появится и надеяться на лучшее